# Окончания названий национальностей в родительном падеже

Tags: грамматика, орфоэпия

Почему форма родительного падежа множественного числа у некоторых национальностей с нулевым окончанием, например:

> англичан, башкир, болгар, бурят, грузин, лезгин, осетин, румын, туркмен, турок, хазар, цыган;

а у некоторых с окончанием, например:

> бедуинов, калмыков, киргизов, коряков, монголов, негров, орочей, таджиков, тунгусов, узбеков, хакасов, хорватов, чукчей, якутов?

Answer (score 4):

Выбор основного окончания ОВ или вариантного нулевого окончания в названиях национальностей связано с фонетическими особенностями основы, то есть выбирается вариант, более удобный для произношения.

Можно отметить, что нулевое окончание чаще встречается после сонорных Л, М, Н, Р.

Нулевое окончание имеют также существительные с суффиксом АНИН/ЯНИН (англичанин – англичане - англичан), а также некоторые  существительные  с изменяющейся основой (боярин – бояре – бояр).