# Как различить пять турок (кофейников) и пять турок (человек)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, грамматика, окончания

1. Как-то в Сети мне встретился **забавный стишок**, где обыгрывалось совпадение форм Р.п. мн.числа  для слов  «турка»  (сосуд для варки кофе) и «турок» (представитель национальности). Например: ***пять турок  (кофейников) и пять турок (человек).***

Действительно, здесь  хочется сказать:  ***пять турков***, но это неверно по словарю. Нулевое окончание является исключением для некоторых национальностей. Но вот Пушкин употреблял форму  «турков», которая потом стала ненормированной.

2. А почему вообще **для названий национальностей**  стала использоваться нулевое окончание при основном окончании ОВ для сущ. м. р. (стол – столов),  что в них такого исключительного?

Вопрос  на эту тему  задавался на форуме, но ответ мне не показался убедительным  (его объяснили особой фонетикой). [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35459/Окончания-названий-национальностей-в-родительном-падеже](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35459/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5)

3. Тогда можно спросить так:  **в чем причина исключительных окончаний  в общем случае** (там всего пять тематических групп: национальности, парные предметы, названия родов войск, единиц измерений, овощей и фруктов),  нельзя ли обойтись без них?

Почему у нас действует **такой принцип**: как мы сказали, так и правильно – мы, мол,  лучше знаем, а иначе будет ошибка. Но если лучше знают, то неплохо бы было обосновать свое решение, если уж **Пушкина корректируют**.

И если разбираться строго, то именно нулевое окончание является **разговорным,** не зря для названий овощей и фруктов он стал **ненормированным** (апельсин – апельсинов), да и рода войск переходят на окончание ОВ.

Еще материал п теме: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1798473-kak-pravilno-pisat-turok-ili-turkov-mnozhestvennoe-chislo.html

Comment: Пожалуйста. https://aif.ru/society/education/turok_ili_turkov_kak_pravilno

Answer (score 2):

1. Серж, **не согласна** я с Есенией Павлоцки, лингвистом-морфологом, экспертом института филологии, массовой информации и психологии Новосибирского государственного педагогического университета.
2. Слово может быть любым по происхождению, но потом оно **вписывается** в словоизменительную систему русского языка. Мы совсем не обязаны **хранить верность**  языку-источнику, для нас это менее важно. В том и заключается наша сила, что мы многое (в том числе даже книжную грамматику)  значительно упростили, в то время как другие языки  в такой же ситуации не сумели это сделать.
3. **Теперь это слово – наше!** А нам удобнее, чтобы оно имело окончание ОВ (и это мнение народа, современных писателей, кстати). Тут еще фонетику надо учитывать, а также влияние других факторов. Например, мы, разумеется, не будем говорить: англичане – англичанов, а вот Пушкин использовал форму «турков

Вот цитата с другого сайта, где приводится материал на эту тему:

*Во времена Пушкина нормой родительного/винительного множественного у этого слова была форма с флексией -ОВ: турков. Сам поэт был блестящим знатоком языка русского (это же не математика, в которой, как сказал лицейский учитель тогда уже начинающего поэта, Пушкин был нулём), а в его повести «Кирджали», названной по имени главного персонажа, говорится, что "война предоставляла возможность обогатиться за счет турков..."*

*В какой-то более поздний период формы ТУРКОВ и ТУРОК мирно сосуществовали, но уже Ушаков в своём словаре (а он создавался в течение 1935–1940 годов), отмечает словоформу ТУРКОВ как устаревшую. В последующих словарях (Ожегова, Ефремовой, Кузнецова) она даже не упоминается: победу одержала словоформа ТУРОК.*

4. **Впечатляет, правда?**  Сначала  лингвисты посчитали форму устаревшей. А теперь рассказывают нам следующее:

*«Слово может иметь какую-либо форму или быть исключением из-за того, что происходило в системе на этапе существования праславянского, старославянского и древнерусского языков. В нашем случае причина в том, что слово турок (мн. ч.) имеет **исконную флексию (окончание) ъ: тоуръкъ.** Это тип склонения основ на -ŏ-: влькъ, ножь. Также существовали основы на -ŭ-: сынъ, свєкры. Последние и стали влиять на основы на -ŏ-, поэтому турков — это **новая форма** слова, испытавшего на себе влияние похожих слов с другим типом склонения **в древнем языке**.*

*Если не понимать это превратно и осознать, что это не порча языка, а естественный процесс **воздействия одних языковых явлений на другие**, то можно сказать: ошибкой разнобой турок — турков не является. Многие из таких пар признаны равноправными и свободно сосуществуют в языке».*

5. Но в паре ***турок – турков*** равноправие вроде не признано, верна только форма ***турок***.  Может быть, это **лингвисты не понимают,** что для слов мужского рода характерно окончание ОВ (стол – столов), а для слов женского рода – нулевое окончание (стена – стен). Почему?   Если в начальной форме окончание нулевое, то оно меняется на ОВ и наоборот. Удобная вещь, так делается различение форм. Или я что-то не понимаю, тогда поправьте меня, пожалуйста.
6. И вот что мне думается. Если когда-нибудь признают **верным окончание ОВ**, то те же лингвисты с такими же умными лицами опять будут учить нас грамотной речи – *не осознаем, мол, и превратно понимаем.*

**Жду вашей критики.** Если вы меня убедите, то я могу изменить свое мнение.

```
Вопрос № 282734
```

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, какая форма в родительном падеже множественного числа у слово турок: турок или турков?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Правильно в родительном падеже мн. числа: ***турок.***

Comment: Язык часто стремится к лаконизму. Ср.: Чулков—чулок, сапогов — сапог, валенков — валенок. А а нашем примере мы вернулись к изначальному варианту.

Comment: Безусловно, стремится, но не всегда, и как мы туда вернулись – это тоже вопрос, надо знать статистику и  историю употребления двух форм.  А что сейчас? В двух из пяти тематических групп нулевое окончание, скорее всего, останется – это единицы измерения и парные предметы. А вот для  овощей и фруктов оно стало ненормированным – мне «килограмм апельсин и помидор» никогда не нравились, просторечием выглядели.  В родах современных войск тоже пишется ОВ, сохраняется только  для пары «отряд гусар и пять гусаров».